# Location and time of impact for a moving point and a moving line segment (Continuous Collision Detection)

Tags: python, collision-detection, game-physics, solver, symbolic-math

I am working on a 2D collider system that breaks up shapes into one possible primitive: impenetrable segments that are defined by two points. To provide collision detection for this system, I am using a static collision detection approach that calculates the distance between the edge of one segment and the currently handled segment (point/line distance) once every frame. If the distance is too small, a collision is triggered during that frame. This works fine but has the known problem of tunneling if one or more bodies exhibit high speeds. So I am tinkering with alternatives.

Now I want to introduce continuous collision detection (CCD) that operates on dynamic points / dynamic segments. My problem is: I don't exactly know how. I do know how to do continuous collision between two moving points, a moving point and a static segment but not how to do CCD between a moving point (defined by point P) and a moving segment (defined by points U and V, both can move completely freely).

[illustration of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgudq.png)

I have seen similar questions beeing asked on SO and other platforms, but not with these exact requirements:

- both point and segment are moving
- segment can be rotating and stretching (because U and V are moving freely)
- collision time and collision point need to be found accurately between two frames (CCD, no static collision test)
- I prefer a mathematically perfect solutiuon, if possible (no iterative approximation algorithms, swept volumes)
- note: the swept line shape will not always be a convex polygon, because of the freedom of the U,V points ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r00Yb.png))
- note: testing for a collision with the swept volume test is inaccurate because a collision point with the polygon does not mean a collision point in the actual movement ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUY6Q.png), the point will have left the polygon once the actual segment has crossed the trajectory of the point)

So far I came up with the following approach, **given**:

- sP (P at start of frame),
- eP (P at end of frame),
- sU (U at start of frame),
- eU (U at end of frame),
- sV (V at start of frame),
- eV (V at end of frame)

**Question**: Will they collide? If yes, when and where?

To answer the question of "if", I found this paper to be useful: [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/brochu-siggraph2012-ccd.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Erbridson/docs/brochu-siggraph2012-ccd.pdf) (section 3.1) but I could not derive the answers to "when" and "where". I also found an alternative explanation of the problem here: http://15462.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2018/article/13 (3rd Question)

**Solution**:

Model temporal trajectory of each point during a frame as linear movement (line trajectory for *0 <= t <= 1*)

- *P(t) = sP * (1 - t) + eP * t*
- *U(t) = sU * (1 - t) + eU * t*
- *V(t) = sV * (1 - t) + eV * t*

(*0 <= a <= 1* represents a location on the segment defined by U and V):

- *UV(a, t) = U(t) * (1 - a) +  V(t) * a*

Model collision by equating point and segment equations:

- *P(t) = UV(a, t)*
- *P(t) = U(t) * (1 - a) + V(t) * a*

Derive a function for the vector from point P to a point on the segment ([see picture of F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quUnP.png)):

- *F(a, t) = P(t) - (1 - a) * U(t) - a * V(t)*

To now find a collision, one needs to find *a* and *t*, so that *F(a, t) = (0, 0)* and *a,t in [0, 1]*. This can be modeled as a root finding problem with 2 variables.

Insert the temporal trajectory equations into *F(a, t)*:

- *F(a, t) = (sP * (1 - t) + eP * t) - (1 - a) * (sU * (1 - t) + eU * t) - a * (sV * (1 - t) + eV * t)*

Separate the temporal trajectory equations by dimension (x and y):

- *Fx(a, t) = (sP.x * (1 - t) + eP.x * t) - (1 - a) * (sU.x * (1 - t) + eU.x * t) - a * (sV.x * (1 - t) + eV.x * t)*
- *Fy(a, t) = (sP.y * (1 - t) + eP.y * t) - (1 - a) * (sU.y * (1 - t) + eU.y * t) - a * (sV.y * (1 - t) + eV.y * t)*

Now we have two equations and two variables that we want to solve for (*Fx, Fy* and *a*, *t* respectively), so we should be able to use a solver to get *a* and *t* to only then check if they lie within [0, 1].. right?

When I plug this into Python sympy to solve:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, nsolve

def main():

    sxP = symbols("sxP")
    syP = symbols("syP")
    exP = symbols("exP")
    eyP = symbols("eyP")

    sxU = symbols("sxU")
    syU = symbols("syU")
    exU = symbols("exU")
    eyU = symbols("eyU")

    sxV = symbols("sxV")
    syV = symbols("syV")
    exV = symbols("exV")
    eyV = symbols("eyV")

    a = symbols("a")
    t = symbols("t")

    eq1 = Eq((sxP * (1 - t) + exP * t) - (1 - a) * (sxU * (1 - t) + exU * t) - a * (sxV * (1 - t) + exV * t))
    eq2 = Eq((syP * (1 - t) + eyP * t) - (1 - a) * (syU * (1 - t) + eyU * t) - a * (syV * (1 - t) + eyV * t))

    sol = solve((eq1, eq2), (a, t), dict=True)

    print(sol)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get a solution that is HUGE in size and it takes sympy like 5 minutes to evaluate.
I cannot be using such a big expression in my actual engine code and this solutions just does not seem right to me.

**What I want to know is**:
Am I missing something here? I think this problem seems rather easy to understand but I cannot figure out a mathematically accurate way to find a time (*t*) and point (*a*) of impact solution for dynamic points / dynamic segments. Any help is greatly appreciated, even if someone tells me that
this is not possible to do like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

I did read *"...like 5 minutes to evaluate..."*

No way too long, this is a real-time solution for many lines and points.

Sorry this is not a complete answer (I did not rationalize and simplify the equation) that will find the point of intercept, that I leave to you.

Also I can see several approaches to the solution as it revolves around a triangle (see image) that when flat is the solution. The approach bellow finds the point in time when the long side of the triangle is equal to the sum of the shorter two.

### Solving for **u** (time)

This can be done as a simple quadratic with the coefficients derived from the 3 starting points, the vector over unit time of each point. Solving for u

The image below give more details.

- The point **P** is the start pos of point
- The points **L1**, **L2** are the start points of line ends.
- The vector **V1** is for the point, over unit time (along green line).
- The vectors **V2**,**V3** are for the line ends over unit time.
- **u** is the unit time
- **A** is the point (blue), and **B** and **C** are the line end points (red)

There is (may) a point in time **u** where **A** is on the line **B**,**C**. At this point in time the length of the lines **AB** (as **a**) and **AC** (as **c**) sum to equal the length of line **BC** (as **b**) (orange line).

That means that when **b - (a + c) == 0** the point is on the line. In the image the points are squared as this simplifies it a little. **b<sup>2</sup> - (a<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup>) == 0**

At the bottom of image is the equation (quadratic) in terms of **u, P, L1, L2, V1, V2, V3**.

That equation needs to be rearranged such that you get **(???)u<sup>2</sup> + (???)u + (???) = 0**

Sorry doing that manually is very tedious and very prone to mistakes. I don`t have the tools at hand to do that nor do I use python so the math lib you are using is unknown to me. However it should be able to help you find how to calculate the coefficients for **(???)u<sup>2</sup> + (???)u + (???) = 0**

[image]

### Update

Ignore most of the above as I made a mistake. **b - (a + c) == 0** is not the same as **b<sup>2</sup> - (a<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup>) == 0**. The first one is the one needed and that is a problem when dealing with radicals (Note that there could still be a solution using  `a + bi == sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` where `i` is the imaginary number).

### Another solution

So I explored the other options.

The simplest has a slight flaw. It will return the time of intercept. However that must be validated as it will also return the time for intercepts when it intercepts the line, rather than the line segment **BC**

Thus when a result is found you then test it by dividing the dot product of the found point and line segment with the square of the line segments length. See  function `isPointOnLine` in test snippet.

To solve I use the fact that the cross product of the line **BC** and the vector from **B** to **A** will be 0 when the point is on the line.

### Some renaming

Using the image above I renamed the variables so that it is easier for me to do all the fiddly bits.

```js
/*
point P is  {a,b}
point L1 is  {c,d}
point L2 is  {e,f}
vector V1 is {g,h}
vector V2 is {i,j}
vector V3 is {k,l}

Thus for points A,B,C over time u    */
Ax = (a+g*u)
Ay = (b+h*u)
Bx = (c+i*u)
By = (d+j*u)
Cx = (e+k*u)
Cy = (f+l*u)

/* Vectors BA and BC at u */
Vbax = ((a+g*u)-(c+i*u))
Vbay = ((b+h*u)-(d+j*u))
Vbcx = ((e+k*u)-(c+i*u))
Vbcy = ((f+l*u)-(d+j*u))

/*
   thus Vbax * Vbcy - Vbay * Vbcx == 0 at intercept 
*/
```

This gives the quadratic

```js
0 = ((a+g*u)-(c+i*u)) * ((f+l*u)-(d+j*u)) - ((b+h*u)-(d+j*u)) * ((e+k*u)-(c+i*u))
```

Rearranging we get

```js
0 = -((i*l)-(h*k)+g*l+i*h+(i+k)*j-(g+i)*j)*u* u -(d*g-c*l-k*b-h*e+l*a+g*f+i*b+c*h+(i+k)*d+(c+e)*j-((f+d)*i)-((a+c)*j))*u +(c+e)*d-((a+c)*d)+a*f-(c*f)-(b*e)+c*b
```

The coefficients are thus

```js
 A = -((i*l)-(h*k)+g*l+i*h+(i+k)*j-(g+i)*j)
 B = -(d*g-c*l-k*b-h*e+l*a+g*f+i*b+c*h+(i+k)*d+(c+e)*j-((f+d)*i)-((a+c)*j))
 C = (c+e)*d-((a+c)*d)+a*f-(c*f)-(b*e)+c*b
```

We can solve using the quadratic formula (see image top right).

**Note** that there could be two solutions. In the example I ignored the second solution. However as the first may not be on the line segment you need to keep the second solution if within the range **0 <= u <= 1** just in case the first fails. You also need to validate that result.

### Testing

To avoid errors I had to test the solution

Below is a snippet that generates a random random pair of lines and then generate random lines until an intercept is found.

The functions of interest are

- `movingLineVPoint` which return the unit time of first intercept if any.
- `isPointOnLine` to validate the result.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("click",test);
const W = 256, H = W, D = (W ** 2 * 2) ** 0.5;
canvas.width  = W; canvas.height = H;
const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
const Tests = 300;
var line1, line2, path, count = 0; 
setTimeout(test, 0);

// creating P point L line
const P = (x,y) => ({x,y,get arr() {return [this.x, this.y]}}); 
const L = (l1, l2) => ({l1,l2,vec: P(l2.x - l1.x, l2.y - l1.y), get arr() {return [this.l1, this.l2]}}); 
const randLine = () => L(P(rand(0, W), rand(0, H)), P(rand(0, W), rand(0, H)));
const isPointOnLine = (p, l) =>  {
    const x = p.x - l.l1.x;
    const y = p.y - l.l1.y;
    const u = (l.vec.x * x + l.vec.y * y) / (l.vec.x * l.vec.x + l.vec.y * l.vec.y);
    return u >= 0 && u <= 1;
}
// See answer illustration for names
// arguments in order Px,Py,L1x,l1y,l2x,l2y,V1x,V1y,V2x,V2y,V3x,V3y
function movingLineVPoint(a,b, c,d, e,f, g,h, i,j, k,l) {
    var A = -(i*l)-(h*k)+g*l+i*h+(i+k)*j-(g+i)*j;
    var B = -d*g-c*l-k*b-h*e+l*a+g*f+i*b+c*h+(i+k)*d+(c+e)*j-((f+d)*i)-((a+c)*j)
    var C = +(c+e)*d-((a+c)*d)+a*f-(c*f)-(b*e)+c*b

    // Find roots if any. Could be up to 2
    // Using the smallest root >= 0 and <= 1
    var u, D, u1, u2;
    // if A is tiny we can ignore
    if (Math.abs(A) < 1e-6) { 
        if (B !== 0) {
            u = -C / B;
            if (u < 0 || u > 1) { return }  // !!!!  no solution  !!!!
        } else { return }                   // !!!!  no solution  !!!!
    } else {
        B /= A;
        D = B * B - 4 * (C / A);
        if (D > 0) {
            D **= 0.5;
            u1 = 0.5 * (-B + D);
            u2 = 0.5 * (-B - D);
            if ((u1 < 0 || u1 > 1) && (u2 < 0 || u2 > 1))  { return }  // !!!!  no solution  !!!!
            if (u1 < 0 || u1 > 1) { u = u2 }        // is first out of range
            else if (u2 < 0 || u2 > 1) { u = u1 }   // is second out of range
            else if (u1 < u2) { u = u1 }            // first is smallest
            else { u = u2 }
        } else if (D === 0) {
            u = 0.5 * -B;
            if (u < 0 || u > 1)  { return }  // !!!!  no solution  !!!!            
        } else { return }                    // !!!!  no solution  !!!! 
    }    
    return u;
}

function test() {
   if (count> 0) { return }
   line1 = randLine();
   line2 = randLine();
   count = Tests
   subTest();
}
function subTest() {
   path = randLine()
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
   drawLines();
   const u = movingLineVPoint(
       path.l1.x, path.l1.y,
       line1.l1.x, line1.l1.y,
       line2.l1.x, line2.l1.y,
       path.vec.x, path.vec.y,
       line1.vec.x, line1.vec.y,
       line2.vec.x, line2.vec.y
   );
   
   if (u !== undefined) { // intercept found maybe
      pointAt = P(path.l1.x + path.vec.x * u, path.l1.y + path.vec.y * u);
      lineAt = L(
          P(line1.l1.x + line1.vec.x * u, line1.l1.y + line1.vec.y * u),
          P(line2.l1.x + line2.vec.x * u, line2.l1.y + line2.vec.y * u)
      );
      const isOn = isPointOnLine(pointAt, lineAt);
      if (isOn) {
          drawResult(pointAt, lineAt);
          count = 0;
          info.textContent = "Found at: u= " + u.toFixed(4) + ". Click for another";
          return;
      }
   }
   setTimeout((--count < 0 ? test : subTest), 18);
}   








function drawLine(line, col = "#000", lw = 1) {
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(...line.l1.arr);
    ctx.lineTo(...line.l2.arr);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function markPoint(p, size = 3, col = "#000", lw = 1) {
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(...p.arr, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawLines() {
   drawLine(line1);
   drawLine(line2);
   markPoint(line1.l1);
   markPoint(line2.l1);
   drawLine(path, "#0B0", 1);
   markPoint(path.l1, 2, "#0B0", 2);
}
function drawResult(pointAt, lineAt) {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
   drawLines();
   markPoint(lineAt.l1, 2, "red", 1.5);
   markPoint(lineAt.l2, 2, "red", 1.5);
   markPoint(pointAt, 2, "blue", 3);
   drawLine(lineAt, "#BA0", 2);
}
```

```css
div {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 12px}
canvas {border: 2px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>
    <div><span id="info">Click to start</span></div>
```

Comment: I think this approach is quite elegant, as it eliminates the need to deal with the location on the segment (*a*) as it was stated in the approach by the OP. Only the time (*t*, or here *u*) needs to be solved for, which I think is neat. Will try out soon. I voted up, but it does not show as I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @PawelBoe I just had a look at my answer again and looks like there is a mistake. The line lengths a, b, c i kept as squares of the lengths. That will not work. They need to be the length ie `b^2 - (a^2+c^2) == 0`  should be `b- (a+c) == 0` Sorry for the error :(

Comment: @PawelBoe Oh dear and that means that the coefficients can not be expressed. This answer will not work as it is.

Comment: But that last approach and explanation are extremely helpful indeed! Thanks a ton for that. I verified the rearrangement myself, I got to slightly different (but equivalent) representations of the coefficients, but that is fine.
I wonder what happens in certain edge cases, like when the segment is static (movement vectors of both edges (0,0)) but the point moves exactily along the segment
- should that not lead to infinite solutions? As it is, works for me though.

Comment: @PawelBoe If a problem can be expressed as a single value (in this case time) and the function is less than a 5th order polynomial this approach is very efficient. I will point out that for your problem, if you translate scale and rotate the whole thing so that L1 is at the origin (0,0) and V2 is a unit vector along the x axis, many of the terms can be removed. Eg the 2nd prob coefs become something like `A = -l-(h*k)+g*l+h; B = -k*b-h*e+l*a+g*f+b-f-a; C = a*f-b*e` as `c = d =  j = 0` & `i = 1` Good if you are repeating parts of the problem. Eg 1 moving line & many moving points.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of @Blindman67's solution I don't understand:

- Solving for  `b^2 - (a^2 + c^2) = 0` instead of `sqrt(b^2)-(sqrt(a^2)+sqrt(b^2)) = 0`
- The returned timestamp being clamped in the range `[0,1]`

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but in any case, I designed a solution that addresses these concerns:

- All quadratic terms are solved for, not just one
- The returned time stamp has no limits
- `sqrt(b^2)-(sqrt(a^2)+sqrt(b^2)) = 0` is solved for, instead of  `b^2 - (a^2 + c^2) = 0`

Feel free to recommend ways this could be optimized:

```
# pnt, crt_1, and crt_2 are points, each with x,y and dx,dy attributes
# returns a list of timestamps for which pnt is on the segment
# whose endpoints are crt_1 and crt_2
def colinear_points_collision(pnt, crt_1, crt_2):
    a, b, c, d = pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.dx, pnt.dy
    e, f, g, h = crt_1.x, crt_1.y, crt_1.dx, crt_1.dy
    i, j, k, l = crt_2.x, crt_2.y, crt_2.dx, crt_2.dy

    m = a - e
    n = c - g
    o = b - f
    p = d - h
    q = a - i
    r = c - k
    s = b - j
    u = d - l
    v = e - i
    w = g - k
    x = f - j
    y = h - l

    # Left-hand expansion
    r1 = n * n + p * p
    r2 = 2 * o * p + 2 * m * n
    r3 = m * m + o * o
    r4 = r * r + u * u
    r5 = 2 * q * r + 2 * s * u
    r6 = q * q + s * s

    coef_a = 4 * r1 * r4  # t^4 coefficient
    coef_b = 4 * (r1 * r5 + r2 * r4)  # t^3 coefficient
    coef_c = 4 * (r1 * r6 + r2 * r5 + r3 * r4)  # t^2 coefficient
    coef_d = 4 * (r2 * r6 + r3 * r5)  # t coefficient
    coef_e = 4 * r3 * r6  # constant

    # Right-hand expansion
    q1 = (w * w + y * y - n * n - p * p - r * r - u * u)
    q2 = 2 * (v * w + x * y - m * n - o * p - q * r - s * u)
    q3 = v * v + x * x - m * m - o * o - q * q - s * s

    coef1 = q1 * q1  # t^4 coefficient
    coef2 = 2 * q1 * q2  # t^3 coefficient
    coef3 = 2 * q1 * q3 + q2 * q2  # t^2 coefficient
    coef4 = 2 * q2 * q3  # t coefficient
    coef5 = q3 * q3  # constant

    # Moves all the coefficients onto one side of the equation to get
    # at^4 + bt^3 + ct^2 + dt + e
    # solve for possible values of t
    p = np.array([coef1 - coef_a, coef2 - coef_b, coef3 - coef_c, coef4 - coef_d, coef5 - coef_e])

    def fun(x):
        return p[0] * x**4 + p[1] * x**3 + p[2] * x**2 + p[3] * x + p[4]

    # could use np.root, but I found this to be more numerically stable
    sol = optimize.root(fun, [0, 0], tol=0.002)
    r = sol.x

    uniques = np.unique(np.round(np.real(r[np.isreal(r)]), 4))
    final = []

    for r in uniques[uniques > 0]:
        if point_between(e + g * r, f + h * r, i + k * r, j + l * r, a + c * r, b + d * r):
            final.append(r)

    return np.array(final)

# Returns true if the point (px,py) is between the endpoints
# of the line segment whose endpoints lay at (ax,ay) and (bx,by)
def point_between(ax, ay, bx, by, px, py):
    # colinear already checked above, this checks between the other two.
    return (min(ax, bx) <= px <= max(ax, bx) or abs(ax - bx) < 0.001) and (min(ay, by) <= py <= max(ay, by) or abs(ay - by) < 0.001)
```

An example (L1 and L2 are endpoints of line):
`P = (0,0) with velocity (0, +1)`
`L1 = (-1,2) with velocity (0, -1)`
`L2 = (1,2) with velocity (0, -1)`

The returned result would be `t=1`, because after 1 time step, P will be one unit higher, and both endpoints of the line will each be one unit lower, therefore, the point intersects the segment at `t=1`.